# How to close Standout Notification?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm using the StandOut API from https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut and when I use the following flags combined in my window:

```
FLAG_DECORATION_SYSTEM | FLAG_WINDOW_HIDE_ENABLE
```

and I have the methods getPersistentNotificationIntent and getHiddenNotificationIntent implemented like this:

```
 @Override
public Intent getPersistentNotificationIntent(int id) {
    return StandOutWindow.getCloseAllIntent(this, MyFloatingWindow.class);
}

@Override
public Intent getHiddenNotificationIntent(int id) {
    return StandOutWindow.getShowIntent(this, MyFloatingWindow.class, id);
}
```

And almost everything works fine. If I close the window using the decoration close button, the notification closes. If press the Notification "Click to close all windows", the notification and windows close. If I hide the window and press the Hidden Notification, the window restores and I can close using the first method. But If I press the hide button and then press the the first notification "Click to close all windows", the windows and the "Hidden" notification close, but I end with a Notification that never closes by itself.

How Can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on this guy github:https://github.com/iBluemind/StandOut
The changes can be found here: https://github.com/iBluemind/StandOut/commit/b6d808772e3612ac13fc2d8bb0b31b0945610295#diff-135c554a227ca9a61dbcae79b7439795R1178